# Is there a way to get code off an old Sharp Wizard?

Tags: hardware, gaming

I have one of these lying around somewhere...

[image: Sharp Wizard]

There was a really cool game on it called Dungeon which I'd love to get the code for. Is that possible?  What would be the steps to try? I do have the serial cable it came with... but no computers with that port.

I figure something that old must not be too hard to decompile... if it were simple to get the data off.

Answer (score 4):

The connection problem is rather easy: Get yourself a [USB/Serial cable/converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20serial%20cable). It might be a bit more work to convert the game itself. Here's the [github page](https://github.com/cjdaniel/sharp-wizard-games) of some guy who did some games for that system back then. Maybe you could find some pointers there.

Comment: Excellent lead which I hadn't found! I asked in an issue there, but he didn't remember anything or have any software or manuals, unfortunately.